# How to add songs/directories to Python MPD playlist

Tags: python, mpd

Having problems finding how to add songs to playlist on Raspberry PI (Jessie Lite)

When I am trying to add file, either giving directory name or file it says :

> mpd.base.CommandError: [50@0] {add} Not found
>   or "bad URI"

I changed  the music directory in mpd.conf to home directory but it didn't help. Can i change MPD music directory from Python?

```
    from mpd import MPDClient
    client = MPDClient()
    client.connect("localhost", 6600)
    client.update()
    //client.add("music/")
    client.add("file.mp3")
```

Aim is just to manage playlist, create and remove songs on demand with python

Answer (score 0):

Answer was found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632225/2838794

```
sudo nano /etc/mpd.conf
```

Inside file:

```
bind_to_address     "/run/mpd/socket"
```

After saving the file

```
export MPD_HOST=/run/mpd/socket
systemctl restart mpd
```